# Sass @content directive includes parent selector

Tags: css, sass

I've written a Sass mixin which works as anticipated, except for one problem: the @content directive seems to be including the *parent selector*, rather than just the content included in parentheses to the mixin.

The mixin:

```
@mixin breakpoint($parameters){

    $query: 'screen and ';

    @each $variable, $value in $parameters {
        $query: $query + '(' + $variable + ':' + $value + ') and ';
    };

    $query: str-slice($query, 0, -5);

    @media #{$query} { @content; };
}
```

I'm trying to use it as in the following:

```
#div {
    background-color: blue;

    @include breakpoint((max-width:500px)) {
        background-color: purple;
    };
}
```

However, this compiles to the following, with the #div id repeated:

```
#div {
  background-color: blue; }
  @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #div {
      background-color: purple; } }
```

The desired output is:

```
#div {
  background-color: blue;
  @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
      background-color: purple;}
}
```

Any help in fixing this problem is very appreciated!

Comment: The output is correct la. It will be compiled to css. So, the 2nd to the last is correct. And your desired output is invalid in css.

Comment: @HermLuna Oh wow, I got so wrapped up with the Sass that I forgot about the final conversion to CSS! Thanks for the help, you're absolutely correct.

Comment: Because, I got also into it. That's a SCSS brother. Sass is different syntax. Much shorter. Dont need to write @mixin. Just using =. Include is using (+) symbol.